# Cube root of complex numbers and treatment of cubic equations

Tags: complex-numbers, cubics, discriminant

Let $Z^3=a+bi$, $b\not=0$

Is it possible for such a complex number to have real roots for $Z=\sqrt[3]{a+bi}$? I did some calculations and found out that it is not but I have a problem:

The equation $x^3-15x+4=0$ has three real roots, however when I put the coefficients into my cubic formula, which always gives the correct answer except for these cases, it does not give me any real solutions because it has an imaginary number, obtained from $\sqrt{-}$ inside the cube root. One of its real roots is $2+\sqrt{3}$, but what I obtain is $2+\sqrt{3} -i2.22 \times 10^{-16}$. Here, the imaginary number is very small and when I replace $x$ with this in equation, it gives me $0$, which means that this value is correct, even if the solutions for the equation are real.

This is where the problem is in the formula:
For $x^3+px+q=0$,

$$\sqrt{\frac{27\times q^2+4\times p^3}{108}}$$

As it is seen here, when $p=-15$ and $q=4$, inside of the square root (which is actually inside of a cube root) becomes negative and makes the inside of the cube root complex number. This results in $3$ complex roots having imaginary coefficients other than $0$. Even if it is very close, as the imaginary part is $-i2.22 \times 10^{-16}$, it is not exactly $0$ where it must be.

The problem is probably about my formula even if I and my friends cannot see, but I would like to learn if such equations are to be treated differently etc.

Comment: @user376343 The remaining roots are $-4$ and $2-\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: my bad, you're right.

Comment: That $10^{-16}$ thing is nothing to worry about, it's just a [roundoff error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error).

Comment: @HansLundmark So this means it is possible to have real roots from a cube root having imaginary coefficient other than zero inside it?

Comment: Yes, Cardano's formula for solving cubics is a sum of two cube roots, whose imaginary parts cancel out. Historically, it was exactly this fact that forced people to take complex numbers seriously. (Claims like “complex numbers were invented to be able to solve all *quadratic* equations”, as you sometimes see in school textbooks, are incorrect.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks, but when I attempt to solve $Z^3 = a + bi$ and $b \neq 0$ by using De Moivre's theorem, I obtain $b=0$ all the time. I wish I could share a picture of my work.

Comment: When you have a single complex number with nonzero imaginary part, then the **cube root of that number** will obviously not be a real number (for the simple reason that the cube of a real number is real). But you were talking about the **solutions of the cubic equation** $x^3-15x+4=0$ being real, weren't you? That's a completely different thing, since those solutions are obtained from a formula where you are adding **two** complex cube roots, both of which can be non-real, but whose imaginary parts cancel out in the summation.

Comment: The formula I have generated on my own for $x^3+px+q=0$ is: $$x = \sqrt[3]{{-q\over2}\pm\sqrt{{27\times q^2+4\times p^3 \over 108}}} - {p\over{3\times \sqrt[3]{{-q\over2}\pm\sqrt{{27\times q^2+4\times p^3 \over 108}}}}}$$

@HansLundmark When I put any values that does not make inside of square root minus, it gives you the correct roots. When I put the values like in my question, inside of the cube root becomes a complex number with nonzero imaginary part because of the extraction of the square root.

Comment: @HansLundmark One of the roots I find after putting values in my question into the equation is $2+\sqrt{3} -i2.22 \times 10^{-16}$, whereas they are all real. $$x_1=-4$$ $$x_2=2+\sqrt{3}$$ $$x_3=2-\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: The trouble with the Tartaglia/Cardano formula is that when the co-efficients are real and there are 3 non-zero real solutions with none of them being the average of the other two, you need  the cube root of a complex, non-real, non-imaginary number, and trying to get it by elementary algebra leads to another cubic, leading to the need for another such cube root, and so on.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I cannot really get the point as I am a high school student. I understand that it becomes harder in those cases but don't understand why and how it leads to unending series of cubic equations. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Tomorrow. I'm sleepy & hence I would need an hour for just a few lines.

Comment: When you say that you find the root $2 +\sqrt3 - i 2.22\times 10^{-16}$, I assume that you mean that that's what you get from a computer or a calculator? But that doesn't mean that the computer is *right*! When you see a discrepancy of size $10^{-16}$ like that, it's surely just an artifact of the finite precision of digital arithmetic, i.e. a **roundoff error** as I wrote already in my first comment. The formula itself is giving you the correct value $2+\sqrt3$, it's just that the computer is giving you an approximation which off by a tiny amount.

Comment: And I also suppose the computer is *actually* giving you something like $3.732050807568877-i2.22\times 10^{-16}$, where the value $2+\sqrt3$ is only *approximated* by the computer. I.e., the real part is also off by a tiny amount.